# SOCIAL_AUTH_FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION in python-social-auth is always None in my custom pipeline

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I'm trying to get session social variable from my template.
I have 2 separate buttons for Signup and Login using key login_type:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}?login_type=1"><img src='img.png'>  </a>

<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}?login_type=2"><img src='img2.png'></a>
```

In my settings:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION = ['login_type']
```

I tried also with:

```
FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION = ['login_type']
```

my custom pipeline:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
'FBAuth.facebook.check_if_exists',     
'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

facebook.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import  redirect, HttpResponse

def check_if_exists(strategy,  request, *args, **kwargs):
    login_type = strategy.request.GET.get('login_type')
    #login_type = strategy.session_get('key') (I tried all cases)
    #login_type = request['login_type']
    #login_type = strategy.request['login_type']
    logger.debug("is_new parameter is %s", kwargs['is_new'])
    logger.debug("login_type is %s", login_type)
    if kwargs['is_new']:
        if login_type == 1:  
            return redirect('/', message ='Specified social account is not yet associate with any existent user, try to Sign up first')
    else: 
        if login_type == 2: 
            return redirect('/', message = 'User for this account is already exist, try to login')
    return None
```

but, in any cases in my logs I always see "login_type is None"

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like form your GET params wrong. You should change

```
<code><pre>?next={{ request.path }}?login_type=1</pre></code>
```

to

```
<code><pre>?next={{ request.path }}&login_type=1</pre></code>
```